# How to convert a Pandas DatetimeIndex to string accordingly

Tags: python, pandas

I define a DatetimeIndex as below.

```
>>> date_rng = pandas.date_range('20060101','20121231',freq='D')

>>> type(date_rng)
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
>>> date_rng[0]
<Timestamp: 2006-01-01 00:00:00>
```

And each element in the 'date_rng' is 'Timestamp', How can I convert it to a string series like below ?

```
>>> pandas.Series(['2006-01-01','2006-01-02','2006-01-03'])
0    2006-01-01
1    2006-01-02
2    2006-01-03
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
>>> date_rng = pd.date_range('20060101','20060105',freq='D')
>>> pd.Series(date_rng.format())

0    2006-01-01
1    2006-01-02
2    2006-01-03
3    2006-01-04
4    2006-01-05
```